# Copy only text from one textbox to another textbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, textbox

I want to copy value of one textbox to another textbox using javascript. When user type value in first textbox then it should automatically copy into another textbox,

Now what my requirement is:
If user type text only then it should copy into another textbox.
If user type numbers then it should not be copied into another one.

Comment: I am new to javascript. So I basically did for copy only and that is working fine.

Comment: if is working fine then mark as right answer. but remember you should add some code that you tried before asking to someone for help. This isn't free work network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var firstText=document.getElementById('firstText'),
    secondtext=document.getElementById('secondText');
firstText.addEventListener('input',function(){
  var val=this.value;
  secondtext.value=val.replace(/[0-9]/g, "");
});
```

```html
<input id="firstText" type="text"/>
<input id="secondText" type="text"/>
```

Comment: Ok @Mr.George. I try to find out.